# Leaflet.draw change polygon filling programmatically

Tags: leaflet, javascript, leaflet-draw

I'm using `Leaflet.draw` to draw and edit polygons.

```
var drawControl = new L.Control.Draw({
    edit: {
        featureGroup: drawnItems,
        edit: { 
            selectedPathOptions: {
                maintainColor: true,
                opacity: 0.3,
                fill: true
            }
        },
    },
    draw: {
        marker: false,
        polyline: false,
        rectangle: false,
        circle: false,
        circlemarker: false,
        polygon: {
            shapeOptions: { color: 'white', opacity: 0.3 },
            allowIntersection: false
        }
    }
});
```

When I'm in Edit mode, I have a checkbox that should enable/disable the polygons filling. I've tried

```
drawControl.options.edit.edit.selectedPathOptions.fill = isChecked;
```

and

```
if (drawControl._toolbars.edit._activeMode.handler)
    drawControl._toolbars.edit._activeMode.handler.options.selectedPathOptions.fill = isChecked;
```

but it doesn't change the filling state.

Is there a way to add or remove the filling while in edit mode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Leaflet.draw` plugin does not have many hooks to get close to it's internals, so some hacking is required:

- Status of edited polygon fill is available in `drawControl._toolbars.edit.options.edit.selectedPathOptions.fill`
- Editing can be disabled by calling `drawControl._toolbars.edit.disable()`
- Editing can be enabled by simulating click on HTML element with has `leaflet-draw-edit-edit` CSS class.

So code for showing/hiding polygon background while being edited could look something like this (tested):

**HTML**

```
<input type="checkbox" oninput="toggleBackground(this)"><label for="layer1"> Show background </label>
```

**JS**

```
function toggleBackground(checkbox) {
  var editButton = document.getElementsByClassName('leaflet-draw-edit-edit')[0];
  drawControl._toolbars.edit.disable();
  drawControl._toolbars.edit.options.edit.selectedPathOptions.fill = checkbox.checked;
  editButton.click();
}
```